# How to authent to Cognos TM1 REST API when server is using CAM

Tags: cognos, cognos-tm1

When to try to get some date using REST API from a Cognos TM1 i get HTTP 401: Unauthorized

Here is my sample with basic authentication header.

```
GET https://testserver:8000/api/v1/Cubes
```

I get HTTP 401: Unauthorized and in heads:

```
WWW-Authenticate: CAMPassport http://testserver:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll, CAMNamespace
```

How to get cookie from CAM so i could use it with REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a nice wiki page which have helped me a lot: [Using CAM authentication with TM1's, OData compliant, RESTful API](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W181f1083f3dd_455f_b2f8_f63c4a9c8010/page/Using%20CAM%20authentication%20with%20TM1's,%20OData%20compliant,%20RESTful%20API)